# Nvidia driver 12.10 failed to install -xubuntu 12.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia

Hi I'm trying to install Nvidia driver for a NV6 vanta with the script from Nvidia located here (http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-ia32-71.86.15-driver.html).

I've edited the blacklist file as well as purged previous Nvidia install.
I did run the install script as root after having closed ligthdm. The script ran until it failed for what's look like a kernel-related problems (???).

Thanks for any help, I'm stuck there for now

**Here's the log file from the failed install:**

```
>nvidia-installer log file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log'  
creation time: Tue Nov 13 17:28:49 2012  
installer version: 1.0.7  

>PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin  

>option status:  
  license pre-accepted               : false  
  update                             : false  
  force update                       : false  
  expert                             : false  
  uninstall                          : false  
  driver info                        : false  
  precompiled interfaces             : true  
  no ncurses color                   : false  
  query latest version               : false  
  OpenGL header files                : true  
  no questions                       : false  
  silent                             : false  
  no recursion                       : false  
  no backup                          : false  
  kernel module only                 : false  
  sanity                             : false  
  add this kernel                    : false  
  no runlevel check                  : false  
  no network                         : false  
  no ABI note                        : false  
  no RPMs                            : false  
  no kernel module                   : false  
  force SELinux                      : default  
  no X server check                  : false  
  no cc version check                : false  
  run distro scripts                 : true  
  no nouveau check                   : false  
  sigwinch work around               : true  
  force tls                          : (not specified)  
  X install prefix                   : (not specified)  
  X library install path             : (not specified)  
  X module install path              : (not specified)  
  OpenGL install prefix              : (not specified)  
  OpenGL install libdir              : (not specified)  
  utility install prefix             : (not specified)  
  utility install libdir             : (not specified)  
  installer prefix                   : (not specified)  
  doc install prefix                 : (not specified)  
  kernel name                        : (not specified)  
  kernel include path                : (not specified)  
  kernel source path                 : (not specified)  
  kernel output path                 : (not specified)  
  kernel install path                : (not specified)  
  precompiled kernel interfaces path : (not specified)  
  precompiled kernel interfaces url  : (not specified)  
  proc mount point                   : /proc  
  ui                                 : (not specified)  
  tmpdir                             : /tmp  
  ftp mirror                         : ftp://download.nvidia.com  
  RPM file list                      : (not specified)  
  selinux chcon type                 : (not specified)  

>Using: nvidia-installer ncurses user interface  
-> License accepted.  
-> Installing NVIDIA driver version 71.86.15.  
-> Running distribution scripts  
   executing: '/usr/lib/nvidia/pre-install'...  
-> done.  
-> The distribution-provided pre-install script failed!  Continue installation  
   anyway? (Answer: Yes)  
-> Performing CC sanity check with CC="cc".  
-> Performing CC version check with CC="cc".  
-> Kernel source path: '/lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/build'  
-> Kernel output path: '/lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/build'  
>ERROR: If you are using a Linux 2.4 kernel, please make sure
       you either have configured kernel sources matching your
       kernel or the correct set of kernel headers installed
       on your system.

       If you are using a Linux 2.6 kernel, please make sure
       you have configured kernel sources matching your kernel
       installed on your system. If you specified a separate
       output directory using either the "KBUILD_OUTPUT" or
       the "O" KBUILD parameter, make sure to specify this
       directory with the SYSOUT environment variable or with
       the equivalent nvidia-installer command line option.

       Depending on where and how the kernel sources (or the
       kernel headers) were installed, you may need to specify
       their location with the SYSSRC environment variable or
       the equivalent nvidia-installer command line option.  
>ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file
       '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  You may find suggestions
       on fixing installation problems in the README available on the Linux
       driver download page at www.nvidia.com.

**Here's my hardware:**

>cool-evo-d500  
    description: Space-saving Computer  
    product: Evo D500  
    vendor: Compaq  
    serial: 6Y24JYHZA04Z  
    width: 32 bits  
    capabilities: smbios-2.3 dmi-2.3 smp-1.4 smp  
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=space-saving cpus=1 uuid=07F4E4D5-EE55-BD11-AB30-085EB767C71C  
  *-core  
       description: Motherboard  
       product: 0788h  
       vendor: Compaq  
       physical id: 0  
       serial: 6Y24JYHZA04Z  
     *-firmware  
          description: BIOS  
          vendor: Compaq  
          physical id: 1  
          version: 686Y2 v2.11  
          date: 02/27/2002  
          size: 128KiB  
          capacity: 448KiB  
          capabilities: pci pnp apm upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd   int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb agp ls120boot zipboot biosbootspecification netboot  
     *-cpu  
          description: CPU  
          product: Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 1.70GHz  
          vendor: Intel Corp.  
          physical id: 5  
          bus info: cpu@0  
          version: 15.1.2  
          slot: XU1  
          size: 1700MHz  
          capacity: 2300MHz  
          width: 32 bits  
          clock: 400MHz  
          capabilities: boot fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm up pebs bts  
          configuration: id=0  
        *-cache:0  
             description: L1 cache  
             physical id: 6  
             slot: Internal L1 Cache  
             size: 8KiB  
             capacity: 20KiB  
             capabilities: burst internal write-back data  
        *-cache:1  
             description: L2 cache  
             physical id: 7  
             slot: Cache L2  
             size: 256KiB  
             capacity: 4MiB  
             capabilities: burst internal write-back data  
     *-memory:0  
          description: System Memory  
          physical id: 21  
          slot: System board or motherboard  
          capacity: 3GiB  
        *-bank:0  
             description: DIMM SDRAM Synchronous 133 MHz (7.5 ns)  
             product: 6MX64PC133CL3 168P  
             vendor: JEDEC ID:7F 98 00 00 00 00 00 00  
             physical id: 0  
             serial: 00F11204  
             slot: XMM1  
             size: 128MiB  
             width: 64 bits  
             clock: 133MHz (7.5ns)  
        *-bank:1  
             description: DIMM SDRAM Synchronous 133 MHz (7.5 ns)  
             product: 16MX64PC133CL3168  
             vendor: JEDEC ID:7F 98 00 00 00 00 00 00  
             physical id: 1  
             serial: BAD22002  
             slot: XMM2  
             size: 128MiB  
             width: 64 bits  
             clock: 133MHz (7.5ns)  
        *-bank:2  
             description: DIMM SDRAM Synchronous 133 MHz (7.5 ns)  
             product: HYS64V32220GU-7.5.  
             vendor: JEDEC ID:C1 49 4E 46 49 4E 45 4F  
             physical id: 2  
             serial: 5CC80F01  
             slot: XMM3  
             size: 256MiB  
             width: 64 bits  
             clock: 133MHz (7.5ns)  
     *-memory:1 UNCLAIMED  
          description: Flash Memory  
          physical id: 22  
          slot: System board or motherboard  
          capacity: 512KiB  
        *-bank UNCLAIMED  
             description: Chip FLASH Non-volatile  
             physical id: 0  
             slot: XU15  
             size: 512KiB  
             width: 4 bits  
     *-memory:2 UNCLAIMED  
          physical id: 0  
     *-memory:3 UNCLAIMED  
          physical id: 2  
     *-pci  
          description: Host bridge  
          product: 82845 845 [Brookdale] Chipset Host Bridge  
          vendor: Intel Corporation  
          physical id: 100  
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0  
          version: 03  
          width: 32 bits  
          clock: 33MHz  
          configuration: driver=agpgart-intel  
          resources: irq:0 memory:f8000000-fbffffff  
        *-pci:0  
             description: PCI bridge  
             product: 82845 845 [Brookdale] Chipset AGP Bridge  
             vendor: Intel Corporation  
             physical id: 1  
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0  
             version: 03  
             width: 32 bits  
             clock: 66MHz  
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master  
             resources: memory:fd000000-fe1fffff memory:f5e00000-f7ffffff  
           *-display UNCLAIMED  
                description: VGA compatible controller  
                product: NV6 [Vanta/Vanta LT]  
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation  
                physical id: 0  
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0  
                version: 15  
                width: 32 bits  
                clock: 66MHz  
                capabilities: pm agp agp-2.0 vga_controller bus_master cap_list  
                configuration: latency=64 maxlatency=1 mingnt=5  
                resources: memory:fd000000-fdffffff memory:f6000000-f7ffffff   memory:f5e00000-f5e0ffff  
        *-pci:1  
             description: PCI bridge  
             product: 82801 PCI Bridge  
             vendor: Intel Corporation  
             physical id: 1e  
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1e.0  
             version: 12  
             width: 32 bits  
             clock: 33MHz  
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master  
             resources: ioport:1000(size=4096) memory:fc200000-fc4fffff  
           *-network  
                description: Ethernet interface  
                product: 82801BA/BAM/CA/CAM Ethernet Controller  
                vendor: Intel Corporation  
                physical id: 8  
                bus info: pci@0000:02:08.0  
                logical name: eth0  
                version: 03  
                serial: 00:08:02:37:c9:bb  
                size: 10Mbit/s  
                capacity: 100Mbit/s  
                width: 32 bits  
                clock: 33MHz  
                capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation  
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e100 driverversion=3.5.24-k2-NAPI duplex=half ip=98.143.214.132 latency=66 link=yes maxlatency=56 mingnt=8 multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s  
                resources: irq:20 memory:fc400000-fc400fff ioport:1000(size=64)  
        *-isa  
             description: ISA bridge  
             product: 82801BA ISA Bridge (LPC)  
             vendor: Intel Corporation  
             physical id: 1f  
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0  
             version: 12  
             width: 32 bits  
             clock: 33MHz  
             capabilities: isa bus_master  
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0  
             resources: irq:0  
        *-ide  
             description: IDE interface  
             product: 82801BA IDE U100 Controller  
             vendor: Intel Corporation  
             physical id: 1f.1  
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.1  
             version: 12  
             width: 32 bits  
             clock: 33MHz  
             capabilities: ide bus_master  
             configuration: driver=ata_piix latency=0  
             resources: irq:0 ioport:1f0(size=8) ioport:3f6 ioport:170(size=8) ioport:376 ioport:2480(size=16)  
        *-usb:0  
             description: USB controller  
             product: 82801BA/BAM USB Controller #1  
             vendor: Intel Corporation  
             physical id: 1f.2  
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2  
             version: 12  
             width: 32 bits  
             clock: 33MHz  
             capabilities: uhci bus_master  
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0  
             resources: irq:19 ioport:2440(size=32)  
        *-usb:1  
             description: USB controller  
             product: 82801BA/BAM USB Controller #1  
             vendor: Intel Corporation  
             physical id: 1f.4  
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.4  
             version: 12  
             width: 32 bits  
             clock: 33MHz  
             capabilities: uhci bus_master  
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0  
             resources: irq:23 ioport:2460(size=32)  
        *-multimedia  
             description: Multimedia audio controller  
             product: 82801BA/BAM AC'97 Audio Controller  
             vendor: Intel Corporation  
             physical id: 1f.5  
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.5  
             version: 12  
             width: 32 bits  
             clock: 33MHz  
             capabilities: bus_master  
             configuration: driver=snd_intel8x0 latency=0
             resources: irq:17 ioport:2000(size=256) ioport:2400(size=64)  
     *-scsi:0  
          physical id: 3  
          logical name: scsi0  
          capabilities: emulated  
        *-disk  
             description: ATA Disk  
             product: ST340014A  
             vendor: Seagate  
             physical id: 0.0.0  
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0  
             logical name: /dev/sda  
             version: 8.01  
             serial: 5JXFR5CA  
             size: 37GiB (40GB)  
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos  
             configuration: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=512 signature=0008da1c  
           *-volume:0  
                description: EXT4 volume  
                vendor: Linux  
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1  
                logical name: /dev/sda1  
                logical name: /  
                version: 1.0  
                serial: 2d2e5c33-b92d-4448-85b6-90888748b41a  
                size: 36GiB  
                capacity: 36GiB  
                capabilities: primary bootable journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized  
                configuration: created=2012-11-11 03:08:28 filesystem=ext4   lastmountpoint=/ modified=2012-11-13 17:05:43 mount.fstype=ext4   mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered mounted=2012-11-13 17:05:43 state=mounted   
           *-volume:1  
                description: Extended partition  
                physical id: 2  
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2  
                logical name: /dev/sda2  
                size: 510MiB  
                capacity: 510MiB  
                capabilities: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended  
              *-logicalvolume  
                   description: Linux swap / Solaris partition  
                   physical id: 5  
                   logical name: /dev/sda5  
                   capacity: 510MiB  
                   capabilities: nofs  
     *-scsi:1  
          physical id: 4  
          logical name: scsi1  
          capabilities: emulated  
        *-cdrom  
             description: DVD-RAM writer  
             product: DVDRAM GSA-4163B  
             vendor: HL-DT-ST  
             physical id: 0.0.0  
             bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0  
             logical name: /dev/cdrom  
             logical name: /dev/cdrw  
             logical name: /dev/dvd  
             logical name: /dev/dvdrw  
             logical name: /dev/sr0  
             version: A104  
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram  
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
```

Comment: `71.86.15` Wow, that's really old. Nvidia isn't releasing drivers compatible for 13+ year old hardware for current kernels/Xorg versions anymore. I would be very surprised if you would get it to work in a recent Ubuntu release. Based on the release date of the latest driver in 2010 I think your best chance is to run Ubuntu 10.04 LTS on this machine.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that Ubuntu-Xubuntu 12.10 isn't installed by default withe the headers. You have to install it by yourself with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms build-essential linux-headers-generic
```

After that, run the installer and use the option to tell it where the sources are.